# Is it true that $\ker((L-\alpha )^n(L-\beta )^m)=\ker(L-\alpha )^n\oplus \ker(L-\beta )^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if Is it true that $$\ker((L-\alpha )^n(L-\beta )^m)=\ker(L-\alpha )^n\oplus \ker(L-\beta )^m$$

where $L:V\to V$ is linear ($V$ a vector space of finite or infinite dimension) and $\alpha \neq \beta $. We suppose $(L-\alpha )^n(L-\beta )^m\neq 0$.

---

When $n=m=1$, I could make the proof. If $v\in V$, I tried to find $v_\alpha \in \ker (L-\alpha )$ and $v_\beta \in \ker(L-\beta )$ s.t. $v=v_\alpha +v_\beta $ as following : suppose there is $v_\alpha \in \ker(L-\alpha )$ and $v_\beta\in \ker(L-\beta ) $ s.t. $v=v_\alpha +v_\beta $, then $$(L-\alpha )v=(L-\alpha )v_\beta =(\beta -\alpha )v_\beta $$, and thus $$v_{\beta }=\frac{(L-\alpha )v}{\beta -\alpha }.$$
similarly, $$v_{\alpha }=\frac{(L-\beta )v}{\alpha -\beta }.$$ Now, I do reverse. I fix $v\in V$, then set $v_\alpha = \frac{(L-\beta )v}{\alpha -\beta }$ and $v_\beta =\frac{(L-\alpha )v}{\beta -\alpha },$ and I proved that $v_\alpha \in \ker(L-\alpha )$, $v_\beta \in \ker(L-\beta )$ and $v=v_\alpha +v_\beta $.

---

When $m=n=2$ I tried to use the same strategy. So, using same notation, I get $$(L-\alpha )^2v=(L-\alpha )^2v_\beta =((L-\beta )+(\beta -\alpha ))^2v_\beta =2(\beta -\alpha )(L-\beta )v_\beta +(\beta -\alpha )^2v_\beta .$$

Now, I don't know what to do with $(L-\beta)v_b$. Any idea on how to continue ?

Comment: Notice $L - \alpha$ and $L - \beta$ commute, so if $v$ belongs to the kernel of $A = (L - \alpha)^n$ or $B = (L - \beta)^m$ then it belongs to the kernel of $C = (L - \alpha)^n (L - \beta)^m.$ In other words, the kernel of $C$ contains $X = \ker A + \ker B.$ I would suspect that $\ker C$ is larger than $X,$ though. Also notice the sum is not direct because you can take $n = m$ and $\alpha = \beta = 0.$

Comment: @WillM.: I supposed that $\alpha \neq \beta $. So it's not true ?

Comment: @metamorphy: Indeed, I suppose $(L-\alpha)^n(L-\beta )^m\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $f$ and $g$ are coprime polynomials, then $$\ker(f(L)g(L))=\ker(f(L))\oplus\ker(g(L))$$

This follows from Bézout's identity: $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x) = 1$.
Just prove both inclusions.

Comment: I think I get it : you set $v_f=b(L)g(L)v$ and $v_g=a(L)f(L)v$ then $v=v_f+v_g$, and $v_f\in \ker(f(L))$ and $g_f=\ker g(L)$ write ? But I'm not so sure why for example $f(L)$ and $b(L)$ commute, i.e. why if $v\in \ker(f(L)g(L))$, then $f(L)v_f=f(L)b(L)g(L)=b(L)f(L)g(L)v=0$. Moreover, why bezout equality hold on $\mathbb Z[X]$ ? I thought that a necessary condition for Bezout hold on a ring $R$ is to be a PID, and if I'm not mistaken, $\mathbb Z[X]$ is not. Is it ?

Comment: @Todd, polynomials in $L$ commute. Also, we’re talking about vector spaces so polynomials over a field.